# man grep | grep "color" gives no result

Tags: bash, unix, grep, command

How come when I try to search the grep manual for the color option with this command

```
man grep | grep "color"
```

I get no result but when I run

```
man grep
```

man outputs this [EDITED]

```
 --colour=[when, --color=[when]]
         Mark up the matching text with the expression stored in GREP_COLOR environment variable.  The possible values of when can be `never', `always' or `auto'.
```

Comment: By "printed manual", do you mean on paper? Then that printed manual probably doesn't fit the installed version of `grep`.

Comment: `man grep | grep color` works for me perfectly.

Comment: Here the regular man command does not send escape sequences when connected to a pipe. Maybe your man command is overloaded, make sure you use the actual command with `command man grep | grep 'color'`.

Comment: @sth I mean what man outputs, this is now edited in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try piping the man page through `col -b` to clean up any special characters before grepping.

For example:

```
man grep | col -b | grep "color"
```

Alternatively, specify `col -b` as your man pager:

```
man -P "col -b" grep | grep "color"
```

You can even set MANPAGER in your shell profile to make this more permanent.

```
export MANPAGER='col -b | less'
```

However, this means that you will lose the pretty colours when viewing man pages.

Answer (score 3):

the output of "man" contains escape sequences (try *man grep|cat -vT*), and the escape sequence to produce the word"color" does not have ASCII sequence "color" in it:

```
   -^H--^H-c^Hco^Hol^Hlo^Hou^Hur^Hr[^H[=^H=_^HW_^HH_^HE_^HN]_^H, -^H--^H-c^Hco^Hol^Hlo^Hor^Hr[^H[=^H=_^HW_^HH_^HE_^HN]
          Surround  the matching string with the marker find in G^HGR^HRE^HEP^HP_^H_C^HCO^HOL^HLO^HOR^HR
          environment variable. WHEN may be 'never', 'always', or 'auto'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
man grep | grep -E 'color'
```

it works perfectly!

Comment: By default set the Terminal to *term-256color*

Comment: The terminal not showing colors is not the issue here. The issue is that grep does not show any result when it should.