# grep initial space

Tags: linux, bash, grep

`man bash | grep "\-d"`

lots of results

`man bash | grep " \-d"`

no results

What's going on here?

Comment: It works correctly for me. It shows only the lines where the -d is followed a whitespace.

Comment: Both give results for me too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually exactly what it looks like. There are no spaces, so grep doesn't find any. If you examine the actual output of `man bash`:

```
man bash > data
```

then take a look at `data` you'll see that what is rendered as a space on screen is actually an escape sequence. What looks like this on screen:

```
May also be specified as -d.
```

is actually this:

```
May also be specified as ^[[1m-d^[[22m.
```

Your terminal interprets these just fine. grep does not.

Comment: Yeah, I see that.  Found my answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600533/man-grep-grep-color-gives-no-result

Comment: Could also be: `May also be specified as -\b-d\bd.`

Answer (score 0):

Did you cut and paste the `" \-d"` from someplace that might have a tab or a non-ascii space in it?  All of the following work ok on my Ubuntu 12 Linux 3.2.0-32 system, where the blank after the first `"` is an  ascii space.

```
man bash | grep  " \-d"
man bash | grep  " -d"
man bash | grep -- "-d"
man bash | grep -- " -d"
man bash | grep -- "-d" |wc
man bash | grep -- " -d" |wc
```

The latter two forms output `43     300    2611` and `12     118     855` respectively.  The `--` which marks end-of-options isn't necessary for the fourth and sixth items, where the pattern starts with a space rather than a dash.

Answer (score 0):

> man bash | grep "-d"

in is case you are searching the string "-d"

it gives me response

but here in

> man bash | grep " -d"

you are searching for a string " -d" (notice the blank space before -d). 
it could be that the 'man bash' has no such string

but it gives response for me
(I cannot post the screenshots)